# How to set the state of parent component in react from inside child component

Tags: reactjs

How to set the state of parent component in react from inside child component? Child component is just a function where I want to set the state of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the setstate into the child component and set the state there.

e.g.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("")

childcomponentFunction(setUser) // function
```

In child component use like below

```
setUser(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  user: "testuser"
}))
```

The above will maintain the prev state as well set the state of parent.